# I want to build a "speedometer"

Tags: limits

I would like to build a "speedometer" ; that is, I have values which represent daily percent increases or percent decreases from the previous day. For example:
Day 1 Value 43.875
Day 2 value 45.125
day 2 represents a 3.7% increase in value from Day 1 which obviously was achieved in 1 day. These percent increases or decreases (as the car may be) is what I want to build my speedometer off of. 
The highest percent increase I have  in a day is 41% and the lowest percent decrease in a day is 36%. I am thinking that if I have two or more successive days of % increases we should be (as per my hypothetical speedometer) still "accelerating" or on the flip side if we have two or more successive days of % decreases we are "decelerating". The speedometer in both accelerating or decelerating examples above would need to take into account a current speed (my speedometer value for that day) that would be an average (I'm assuming) of the prior days contributing % increases and  % decreases. Any ideas on how to create this in excel or other program. My apologies if I didn't explain this well. I can reword it if you ask clarifying questions. Thank you.

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: It sounds like you're after an _accelerometer_ rather than a speedometer? I think it might be helpful to think about what units everything should be in (e.g., quantity per time is usually the "speed" of something)

Comment: Where are you recording the current speed? The value on each day is the change from the previous day and thus the first day's value is something to consider what will it be and how to ensure it isn't used unfairly here.

Answer (score 0):

These percent increases have to do with stock prices, so there will be an official beginning (when the stock was traded for the first time). I have done nothing yet for constructing in excel because I am not sure how to write formulas for this. Thank you for your responses.